# Why this clearing input buffer not run?

Tags: java, string, buffer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
//java program for accepting an integer, an double and a set of string from the user.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        String s= scan.nextLine();

        scan.next();
        scan.nextLine();//clearing input buffer.
        //printing the inputs taken from the user.
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question as it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Why are you calling `nextLine()` twice? and what does your input look like?

Answer (score -1):

When you press enter key the `\n` special character is kept in buffer. So after `double d= scan.nextDouble();` the buffer will keep `\n` and store it in String s in line `String s= scan.nextLine();`. To get rid of that simply modify your code like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d= scan.nextDouble();

// this will clear the '\n'
scan.nextLine();

String s= scan.nextLine();

//printing the inputs taken from the user.
System.out.println("String: " + s);
System.out.println("Double: " + d);
System.out.println("Int: " + i);
```

Another way to deal with that is to always scan using `nextLine();` and parsing it the way you want. Doing so makes it easier to check if the data entered by user are valid.

Comment: He is calling it after String s= scan.nextLine(); 
That way the '\n' produced when entering data in double d= scan.nextDouble(); will not be consumed and will be stored in String s.

Comment: Correct, but your answer tells him to do exactly that, and he is already doing it, twice, so how exactly does you answer improve over what he's already doing?

Comment: @EJP It is the order in which he calls nextLine()

Comment: Calling it right before scaning the String consumes '\n'

Comment: @EJP You shouldn't downvote an answer before seeing closely what it says

Comment: It is indeed not only the order but the number of times he calls `nextLine()`, but there is nothing about that in your answer. And you have no information whatsoever about who downvoted your answer.

Comment: @EJP You can clearly see in my answer that I got rid of the other nextLine()

Comment: I can clearly see in your answer that you didn't even comment on that, let alone explain why it would solve the problem. Whatever the actual problem may be, which is indeterminate given that he hasn't specified his input.

Comment: @EJP I didn't comment on that because only one nextLine() would do the job. I wrote MODIFY your code to what I wrote. Not just add a line. Anyway it is clear, but maybe not commented. He could have asked and I would tell him what I forgot to write. Yes the actual problem is not well specified.